# Objective C: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error

Tags: objective-c

I am a newbie, writing a simple program and while there are no warnings/errors during compilation. I am getting a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. Will appreciate any help with this:

```
    int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        moviedatabase *movie1=[[moviedatabase alloc] init];

    [movie1 addMovieWithName:@"DDLJ" andyear:1789 andlength:360 andGenre:Horror];
    [movie1 printAll];
    [movie1 release];

    [pool drain];

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the moviesdatabase class and movies class which it is inheriting:

```
@interface moviedatabase :  movies{
//no variables in the class
}

-(void) addMovieWithName: (NSString *)mname andyear: (int) myear andlength: (int) mlength andGenre: (enum Genre) mgenre; 
-(void) printAll;

@end

@interface movies : NSObject {
NSString    *name;
int year;
int length;
enum Genre {Comedy,Drama,Horror,Action} genre;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int year;
@property (nonatomic) int length;
@property (nonatomic) enum Genre genre;

-(id) initWithName: (NSString *)name andyear: (int) year andlength: (int) length andGenre: (enum Genre) genre; 

@end
```

Including the implementation of moviedatabase:

```
 #import "moviedatabase.h"


 @implementation moviedatabase

 -(void) addMovieWithName: (NSString *) mname andyear: (int) myear andlength: (int) mlength andGenre: (enum Genre) mgenre
   {
         name=mname;
  year=myear;
  length=mlength;
  genre=mgenre;

  }

-(void) printAll;
 {
  NSLog(@"name=%@, year=%@, length=%@, genre=%@",name,year,length,genre);
 }

 @end
```

Comment: Perhaps showing us the `moviedatabase` class might help. Also, when you show source code, highlight the code in the question editor and press the 010101 icon at the top to indent it.

Comment: As an addendum to @BoltClock's comment, from what we can see in the `main` function nothing is out of order, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is stemming from the code inside of the `addMovieWithName` or `printAll` methods.

Comment: @Vatsaf, We also need to see the `@implementation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `printAll` method uses `%@` instead of `%i` for `int` variables.

This:

```
- (void)printAll
{
    NSLog(@"name=%@, year=%@, length=%@, genre=%@", name, year, length, genre);
}
```

Should look like this:

```
- (void)printAll
{
    NSLog(@"name=%@, year=%i, length=%i, genre=%i", name, year, length, genre);
}
```

In `NSLog()`, `%@` is used for `NSObject`s, and standard `printf` format strings are used for other C primitives, e.g. `%i` for `int`, `%u` for `unsigned int`, `%f` for `float`.